# How to make a CMS for a existing website?

Tags: content-management-system

I'm looking for developing a website that should allow my clients to update and edit the contents of the website. Is it better to use CMS or develop an interface?

I've tried working with Wordpress.

Getting a few ideas for developing a Website that allows Client engagement in site activities.